Convert graphql to json
I need to insert a variable endCursor inside the StringContent however I get Bad Request. This endCursor contains string value.
content = new StringContent("{\"query\": \"query { products { complexity request_id data(first:10 after:\"" + endCursor + "\"){ edges { cursor node { id sku name warehouse_products { id warehouse_id warehouse_identifier inventory_bin on_hand } } } pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage } } } }\"}", null, "application/json");

This is a working request but failed with Bad Request error after adding this after:\"" + endCursor + "\"
This is the equavalent graphql:
query { 
    products { 
        complexity 
        request_id 
        data(first:10 after:"Y3Vyc29yMQ=="){ 
            edges { 
                cursor
                node { 
                    id 
                    sku 
                    name 
                    warehouse_products { 
                        id 
                        warehouse_id 
                        warehouse_identifier
                        inventory_bin
                        on_hand
                    }
                }
            }
            pageInfo {
                endCursor
                hasNextPage
            }
        }
    }
}

Please help me fix this one or another way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Which value does endCursor contain? Have you checked the resulting string after concatenation? What does it look like? Is it the expected string? Also do you get any more details maybe in the request other than just 400 or are there server logs (if you have access to those) which could tell you more?
